# Loop does not repeat value in a Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I apologize if the title is poorly written, as I am unsure of what exactly to call this!

I have a pretty basic table setup: employees, and employees_deductions.  I want to join these two and display the content in a table with php.

I get the employees:

```
$employees = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from employees");
```

I then loop through the `$employees`, and on each one, I get the deductions, then display them in a table: (code below simplified)

```
foreach($employees as $emp) {
  $deductions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM employee_deductions WHERE employee_id = $this_employee_id");

  foreach($deductions as $ded) {
    <tr>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>deduction</td>
    </tr>
  }

}
```

My question is how can I have that first cell that contains "name" above BLANK if the cell in the row directly above it contains the same exact "name"?

What I'm getting:

```
+------+-----------+
| name | deduction |
+------+-----------+
| John |       100 |
| John |       142 |
| John |       204 |
| Mary |       200 |
| Mary |       340 |
+------+-----------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------+-----------+
| name | deduction |
+------+-----------+
| John |       100 |
|      |       142 |
|      |       204 |
| Mary |       200 |
|      |       340 |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Are you writing PHP and HTML in one sequence without starting or ending PHP ? And for answer please try group by of mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an extra variable where you will store the last name or id, then compare it to the current name/id. If it matches, just display an empty column, and if not, show the name.

Assuming that your `SELECT` query is in order by name, this is doable:

```
foreach($employees as $emp) {

    $lastid = ''; /* WHERE YOU WILL STORE THE LAST ID OR NAME; JUST LEAVE IT EMPTY AT FIRST */

    $deductions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM employee_deductions WHERE employee_id = $this_employee_id");

    foreach($deductions as $ded) {
        echo '<tr>';
        // JUST REPLACE THE CORRESPONDING VARIABLE/CONDITION BELOW
        echo (empty($lastid) || $lastid != $this_employee_id)?'<td>name</td>':'<td></td>';
        echo '<td>deduction</td>
              </tr>';

        $lastid = $this_employee_id; /* STORE THE CURRENT ID/NAME TO THIS VARIABLE */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you code run in right,
I will do like this

```
foreach($employees as $emp) {
  $deductions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM employee_deductions WHERE employee_id = $this_employee_id");

  //becasue same employee_id must have same name
  $show = 0;
  foreach($deductions as $ded) {
    <tr>
       if ($show == 0) {
         <td>name</td>
       } else {
         <td></td>
       }
       <td>deduction</td>
    </tr>
    $show++;
  }

}
```